# OpenVPN AS can not ping client's private subnet

Tags: openvpn, ping, raspbian, vpn-client

The setup I am trying is as follows:

```
Device A (PLC, static IP=10.10.10.11) 
        |
        | eth0 connection 
        |
Device B (raspberry B 3,  Jessie) 
          VPN IP. 10.8.0.160
        |
        | OpenVPN (connected via Wi-Fi)  
        |
Device C (laptop, Ubuntu, OpenVPN Server Access)
          VPN IP 10.8.0.1
```

My Server's `ip route`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.8.0.0/27 dev as0t0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1 
10.8.0.32/27 dev as0t1 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.33 
10.8.0.64/27 dev as0t2 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.65 
10.8.0.96/27 dev as0t3 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.97 
10.8.0.128/27 dev as0t4 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.129 
10.8.0.160/27 dev as0t5 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.161 
10.8.0.192/27 dev as0t6 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.193 
10.8.0.224/27 dev as0t7 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.225 
169.254.0.0/16 dev tun0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.61 metric 600
```

I have also enabled routing in Admin web GUI.

[With these settings I can ping Server from client and Vice Versa, also can ping PLC from client which is direct connection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56K9R.png)

but I cannot ping PLC from server.

[but when this is enabled I can't even ping PLC from client even though its a direct connection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtVod.png)

Please help what else needs to be done.
Stuck here forever.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have one query...In the first network with Device A and Device  B there is no router in between. The IP's are assigned statically. Is that causing error? Do I need to add router or make R-pi a router??

Answer (score 0):

The server needs a route towards `10.10.10.11` via `10.8.0.160`.

Something like `route 10.10.10.11 255.255.255.255 10.8.0.160` in the openvpn config on the server should do the trick (I'm assuming it's a peer-to-peer connection).

Additionally, IP forwarding needs to be enabled on Device B (`echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`), and Device A needs a route towards `10.8.0.1` via Device B. (If Device B is the default gw of Device A, then this should already be taken care of.)

Comment: Korn still not working. I added the route but still can't ping Device A from Device C.

Comment: Did you carry out all three steps? If so, please look at tcpdump output on both relevant interfaces of device B.